# create database with sqlalchemy on openshift

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, openshift

When i just deployed my app to openshift but when i run it, i get error 500. On inspecting the log file, i realize that sqlalchemy cannot find the database.
This is the error log

```
 python/logs/error_log-20140308-000000-EST <==
[Sat Mar 08 17:47:31 2014] [error] [client 127.10.252.129]     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
[Sat Mar 08 17:47:31 2014] [error] [client 127.10.252.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/531b3df4500446dfb400007a/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 867, in _execute_context
[Sat Mar 08 17:47:31 2014] [error] [client 127.10.252.129]     context)
[Sat Mar 08 17:47:31 2014] [error] [client 127.10.252.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/531b3df4500446dfb400007a/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 324, in do_execute
[Sat Mar 08 17:47:31 2014] [error] [client 127.10.252.129]     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
[Sat Mar 08 17:47:31 2014] [error] [client 127.10.252.129]   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
[Sat Mar 08 17:47:31 2014] [error] [client 127.10.252.129]     self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
[Sat Mar 08 17:47:31 2014] [error] [client 127.10.252.129]   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
[Sat Mar 08 17:47:31 2014] [error] [client 127.10.252.129]     raise errorclass, errorvalue
[Sat Mar 08 17:47:31 2014] [error] [client 127.10.252.129] OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1046, 'No database selected') 'DESCRIBE `users`' ()
```

I'm lost. The openshift documentation says a database is created with the same name as you app immediately you create an app

Comment: Could it be possible that you are missing a database in your connection string? I don't know anything about openshift though.

Comment: What database are you trying to use with sqlalchemy?

Comment: @PaulMorie i'm using mysql 5.5

Comment: OK, will you post the portion of your code where you're making the connection to the db, or giving the coordinates for the db to sqlalchemy?

Comment: @PaulMorie This is the connection string used by openshift import os
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL']
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False

Comment: scalable, or non scalable?

Comment: Non scalable @PaulMorie

Comment: @azdonald, can you post your code initialize sqlalchemy?

Comment: app = Flask(__name__)

oauth = OAuth(app)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The openshift tutorial on flask uses PostgreSQL and gives the connection string as

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL']
```

i used MySQL and changed it to

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL']
```

which was what caused the error as you have to pass the app name(which is also the name of the database) to the URI. So the connection string becomes

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL'] + os.environ['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME']
```